# ember-1.0.pre.js on Opera 'Unhandled Error: Object.defineProperty: first argument not an Object'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, opera

My application in Opera (12.02 build 1578, latest version on windows 64 bit) using ember.1.0.pre.js is throwing

`'Unhandled Error: Object.defineProperty: first argument not an Object'`

```
g ember-1.0.pre.min.js:9
(anonymous) ember-1.0.pre.min.js:9
(global) ember-1.0.pre.min.js:9
```

However I don't get this error in Chrome, Safari or Firefox. I tried to use the debug build to get more information however when I use ember-1.0.pre.js **(debug build)** I get this error thrown

```
"Unhandled Error: assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.beta.5 or greater"

Ember.assert ember-1.0.pre.js:43
(anonymous) ember-1.0.pre.js:17765
(global) ember-1.0.pre.js:17956
```

note: I am using requirejs, the implementation works on all but opera

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include `handlebars.js` on your HTML page in the correct order i.e. before `ember.js` in the order of loading the javascripts.

```
<script src="/javascripts/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/ember.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and not

```
<script src="/javascripts/ember.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I used to get the same error -- 
`"Unhandled Error: assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.beta.5 or greater"` 
before I realized that the load order was wrong. The error disappeared after I set it right.

Edit: Just noticed that you have mentioned you are using `requirejs`. I am not very well-versed with requirejs but from what I know, make sure you use the shim config correctly:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'ember': {
            deps: ['handlebars', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Ember'
        }
    }
});
```